# On Blogger, how to prevent it interfering with an image?

Tags: blogger

I am in HTML editing mode, and I insert an image with:

```
<p><img src="http://url-of-image/"/></p>
```

Then, Blogger turns it into:

```
<p><img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/......"></p>
```

How can I get Blogger to leave the image source alone?

Comment: Does it only happen with certain images, or images from certain URLs?  I've never noticed that.

Comment: @freginold Good question. It seems to happen with all images. I think it might be a theme setting.

Comment: Have you tried any other themes or settings? Which theme are you using? I use Amazon affiliate links and those `img` sources don't change to a Google link.